# Capturing repeated word sequence

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, to match text pattern like `a11a`, `g22g`, `x33x` below regex works fine

```
  ([a-z])(\d)\g2\g1
```

Now i want to match repeating groups like similar to above but having space in between words like

`abcd 101 abcd 101` ( *catch this entire string in single regex pattern in one single line text or  a paragraph* )

How to do this...i tried below pattern but it wont work

```
    ([a-zA-Z]*\s)([0-9]*\s)\g1\g2 
#logic is : words followed by space in 1 group and 
#numbers followed by space in 2nd group
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hV3wA6)

Also, please explain why the above regex fails to capture the desired text pattern!!!

**EDIT**

One more complication :

assume that pattern is something like

```
[words][space][numbers][space][words][space][numbers]
#assume all [numbers] and [word] are same
```

....so in last `[numbers]` case, `[space]` doesn't follow, how to filter then...because regex group capture like:

`([0-9]*\s)` certainly fails to capture last part if it is repeated, and

`([0-9]*)` would fail to capture mid-part if it is repeated!! ??
 [**Regex 101**](http://regex101.com/r/zN1tR9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your regex expects a space at the end, because you have included the space in the captures.

Try instead:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)\s\g1\s\g2
```

Comment: that was pretty dumb of me...ok check this : http://regex101.com/r/zN1tR9, i have removed `\s` followed in by words...how do i match up the string then?? assume that pattern is something like `[words][space][numbers][space][words][space][numbers]` ....so in last `[number]` case, space doesnt follow, how to filter then??

Comment: @NoobEditor: In that case you haven't allowed for a space after the digits. `([a-zA-Z]*\s)([0-9]*)\s\g1\g2` works fine.

Comment: my doubt is in `([a-zA-Z]*\s)([0-9]*)\s\g1\g2` , we have 2 `\s`, one from the first capture group, second from `\s\g1\g2` ...how does it takes these 2 for matching?? i mean..`\s\g1\g2` means space in between `g1` and `g1`, that would make 2 space after  `[a-zA-Z]*` ...wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`([0-9]*\s)` = `101` with space

so `\g2` doesn't match with `101` as it doesn't have any space at the end.

**Update:** Working regex `([a-zA-Z]*\s)([0-9]*)\s\g1\g2` for input `abcd 101 abcd 101`

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nT8iS1)

More example:

```
([a-zA-Z]*\s)     ([0-9]*)       \s         \g1          \g2
   abcd+space        101        Space       abcd+space    101
```

Comment: that was pretty dumb of me...ok check this : http://regex101.com/r/zN1tR9, i have removed `\s` followed in by words...how do i match up the string then?? assume that pattern is something like `[words][space][numbers][space][words][space][numbers]` ....so in last `[number]` case, space doesnt follow, how to filter then??

Comment: @NoobEditor There is a space between `abcd 101` and `abcd 101`. But there is no space between `\g1` and `\g2`. Placing a `\s` between `\g1\g2` will do it for you!

Comment: @NoobEditor `\s` goes before the `\g1\g2` :-) as you have space between the two repeated groups `g1g2 g1g2`.

Comment: i am fumbling a lot in dealing with capturing groups!! :\

Comment: Yeah sure http://regex101.com/r/nT8iS1 if you read the description from the text at the bottom of the link, it will help you to learn faster!

Comment: one more doubt :) ...  in plain english , `\s\g1\g2` means space between capture grp 1 and 2...??

Comment: @NoobEditor yes it is :-)

Comment: and m just going on posting comments for chat to open up... **doubt :** `g1` has `space` in it...so `\s\g1\g2` means there is `2 space` between g1 and g2....how is it matching then??

Comment: *if its late in your place and you plan to sleep, you can reply back tomorrow...no probs!!* :)

Comment: No, that is wrong. `\s\g1\g2` means a whitespace character, followed by the contents of capture group 1, followed by the contents of capture group 2.